# Transparent Proxy For Individual Web Apps?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, authentication, ntlm, transparent-proxy

At work, I perform automated testing of our front-end web apps that use Active Directory for authentication. One tool (Sahi) uses a local proxy to go between the web app and the user's browser, to inject javascript in each page before delivering them to the user, for testing purposes.

On Windows 7, this tool's proxy can't authenticate with our web app. It's not our network that requires authentication - it's each individual web app, of which there are several.

I figured that I could use a transparent "proxy to the proxy" that would handle the NTLM authentication, but the proxies (CNTLM, NTLMAPS) I could find all wanted to be pointed at the address of our internal network proxy, which I don't think we have.

Are there transparent proxies that will forward my authentication to particular sites instead of assuming that I connect to some internal address that expects authentication for everything (only the web apps need authentication, which they handle themselves, if I understand correctly)? Or is likely that my corporate network does in fact have some kind of internal proxy server that forwards web application names to IP addresses on our network? If so, is there any way that I can find this proxy's address without interrupting someone from my busy IT department?

Or is there a better way to phrase my question so that my IT department will know what I'm talking about if I ask them? I'm not sure if there is even such a thing as an "internal corporate proxy" for me to ask them about, or if such a thing has a different name, etc.

Comment: Yeah, tracert gives me one IP address before going to any other machine on our network, which I'm guessing is our router, and cntlm can't use that as a target address. There is no corporate internet proxy / ISA proxy that that I'm aware of.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. I started playing around NTLM group policy settings on my windows 7 remote vm (stupid... I lost another vm doing something similar >.>) and authentication works.

Comment: If your question is no longer relevant, feel free to delete it.